# Preloading a customized Windows 10 installation image

Tags: boot, windows-10, unattended

In short: When I boot from the preloaded installation, the setup wipes the hard disk and after the next reboot it (obviously) fails to load the OS.
--> What setting am I missing to keep setup from reinitializing the boot disk during setup?

---

In long:
For a test case I used an original Win10 ISO downloaded from Microsoft.
Below are the steps I followed to preload the image on the disk: (note: it’s a VM so I could mount the ISO)

- Boot from the ISO
- Select preferred language/keyboard layout and click next
- On the next screen DON’T  select ‘Install Now’ but select ‘Repair this computer’
- In the menu that appears select ‘Troubleshoot’ --> ‘Advanced Options’ --> ‘Command Prompt’
- Enter following commands in the command prompt:

  `diskpart 
    select disk 0 
    clean 
    convert mbr 
    create partition primary 
    select partition 1  active 
    format fs=ntfs label=System quick 
    assign letter c 
    exit 
  xcopy d:\ c:\ /E /V 
  c:
  cd \boot 
  bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr /force 
  exit`
- Select ‘Turn off your PC’

Booting the VM loads the Windows setup and I could install Win10 on the drive.  I do end up with a dual boot between Windows10 and Windows Setup, but that can be fixed with bcdedit after which the setup files can be erased.
So this shows the preload is at least possible.

In the next step I created a customized image using ‘Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer’ (ICD) and load it with all settings, drivers and scripts I need to make a fully unattended installation, exported the image and created a bootable ISO using oscdimg.exe.
Booting from the customized ISO gives me my desired result: A completely installed, configured and customized Win10 installation with hardly any clicks.

Next step is to preload the customized installation media on the hard disk.
For this I use much the same procedure as in the test case with the only difference that I mount the customised ISO before I perform the xcopy.
Since there are no configuration options in ICD for disk layout (at least not that I could find), the setup uses an automatic partitioning scheme which wipes the drive.
This obviously results in a failed installation

Trying to fix:
In the customized installation media I found the file \sources\ Autounattend.xml with the following section:
(note: original file has no line breaks, I formatted the relevant part for readability)

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows-provisioning">
 <Customizations>
    [large list of settings I selected in ICD, removed here for brevity]
 </Customizations>
 <UnattendedSetup>
  <InstallWindows>
   <WimImage>
    <Path>install.wim</Path>
    <ImageIndex>1</ImageIndex>
   </WimImage>
    <Destination>
    <Disk>BootDisk</Disk>
    <Partition>Automatic</Partition>
    <ProvisionDisk>True</ProvisionDisk>
   </Destination>
  </InstallWindows>
  <EnableCompactOS>False</EnableCompactOS>
  <ProductKey>PromptAtOOBE</ProductKey>
  <Eula>PromptAtOOBE</Eula>
 </UnattendedSetup>
 <Provisioning>
  <ProvisioningPackages>
   <ProvisioningPackage>ProvisioningPackages\ICD_Customizations.ppkg</ProvisioningPackage>
  </ProvisioningPackages>
 </Provisioning>
</Settings>`

I tried modifying this file with

`<Destination>
<Disk>BootDisk</Disk>
<WillWipeDisk>false</WillWipeDisk>
<Partition>Automatic</Partition>
<ProvisionDisk>True</ProvisionDisk>
</Destination>`

`<Destination>
<Disk>BootDisk</Disk>
<WillWipeDisk>false</WillWipeDisk>
<Partition>Manual</Partition>
<ProvisionDisk>False</ProvisionDisk>
</Destination>`

`<Destination>
<Disk>BootDisk</Disk>
<WillWipeDisk>false</WillWipeDisk>
</Destination>`

`<Destination>
<Disk>BootDisk</Disk>
<Partition>Manual</Partition>
<ProvisionDisk>False</ProvisionDisk>
</Destination>`

`<Destination>
<Disk>BootDisk</Disk>
</Destination>`

All of which either results in a wiped disk or a reboot loop

Left and right on the internet I’ve found more possible switches regarding disk configuration in a windows answer file but the iterating all of them will take A LOT of time and I’m so far unable to find a clear reference sheet for everything allowed/mandatory inside `<Destination></Destination>` so I'd like to ask here:

--> Does anyone know the correct code to fix the diskwipe/reboot loop
--> Does anyone know of a resource where all options/switches for this XML section are mentioned and/or explained

Comment: Does the reboot loop restart the preinstalled-setup?

Comment: Yes, each time the windows setup  is launched again. When I go look at the content of the drive, everything looks the same (no windows, users or program files folder)

Comment: So, best guess:
1) Setup preinstall and **set the install to boot the setup)
2) Run the setup, but the 'boot to this setup' does not get changed even though an OS is installed. It might add a second boot entry, but not change the default.
3) Reboot. Start the default (which is not what we want this time).

Comment: I don't think this is the case for following reasons: - The setup flashes only for an instant, goes black and reboots after 30~45s. - The content of the disk remains the same. - Booting from the customised ISO (not preloading it) it takes about 10 min before the first reboot. - The test case does this fine and also takes about 10 min before the first reboot